# Anyone using Windowless mode in a Silverlight business app without animations?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

We have a standard business application written in Silverlight for which we need to use Windowless Mode.  This "feature" to use a Telerik Silverlight component.

Using Google I have found lots of bad things that can go wrong with windowless mode with regards to mixing HTML content and animations.  I am interested in knowing if bad things will happen if the silverlight app is the only content in the browser window.

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience.

Mike

Answer (score 2):

Windowless actually improved the way Silverlight and html interact.  Without windowless set, Silverlight is just painted on top of the html.  Setting windowless is the only way to have html on top of silverlight or to have a transparent silverlight application.

The major downside to windowless is that it forces silverlight to be software rendered instead of hardware rendered.  This means that the power of the GPU can't be utilized for things like animations.

If the silverlight app is the only thing in the browser window, the only real difference between windowless and not is the performance issue mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

An example of Windowless mode with lots of animations and mixed in HTML is the [Office Labs Silverlight site](http://www.officelabs.com/). NOTE: You need to click the "Try in Silverlight" on the plain HTML version of the site to see the Silverlight version.

That site uses a floating iframe to display HTML inside of the Silverlight content. Most of the animations work just fine, however, you can't scale the HTML very easily so the HTML is hidden while some of the animations are performed.

Let me know if you have any other questions about the site.